# C++ copy_if lambda capturing std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This is a follow up question from here: [C++ - Developing own version of std::count_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568278/c-developing-own-version-of-stdcount-if/20568936)?

I have the following function:

```
// vector for storing the file names that contains sound 
std::vector<std::string> FilesContainingSound; 

void ContainsSound(const std::unique_ptr<Signal>& s)
{
    // Open the Wav file 
    Wav waveFile = Wav("Samples/" + s->filename_); 

    // Copy the signal that contains the sufficient energy 

    std::copy_if(waveFile.Signal().begin(), waveFile.Signal().end(), 
                 FilesContainingSound.begin(), [] (const Signal& s) {

                     // If the energy bin > threshold then store the 
                     // file name inside FilesContaining
                 }
}
```

But to me, I only need to capture the string "filename" inside of the lambda expression, because I'll only be working with this. I just need access to the `waveFile.Signal()` in order to do the analysis.

Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
std::vector<std::string> FilesContainingSound;
std::copy_if(w.Signal().begin(), w.Signal().end(), 
             FilesContainingSound.begin(), [&] (const std::unique_ptr<Signal>& file) {

                 // If the energy bin > threshold then store the 
                 // file name inside FilesContaining
             });
```

Comment: Please check your spelling.

Comment: In case of doubt, you could use automatic capture, `[=]` or `[&]`.

Comment: As Manu says, since `copy_if` won't keep around a copy of your lambda, you can safely use automatic by-reference capture (`[&]`) and get access to all your variables by reference.

Comment: @zneak I've tried using `[&] () { // do something });` but just comes up with an error saying it cannot convert const double to string

Comment: I think there has to be a return type. I've given the return type as a string and as a const std::unique_ptr still errors

Comment: It sounds more like a mistake in your `// do something` than a lambda problem. The return type for this lambda needs to be boolean since it's used for `copy_if`.

Comment: @zneak Nopee :( In my // do something it is just comments. I'll update my post

Comment: Would it be possible that the type of `*w.Signal().begin()` is not `std::string`?

Comment: @zneak - Oh, no. It's of type double.. So it has to be double. So in the lamda expression I can still access the filename stored inside the unique_ptr?

Comment: Yes (assuming you get it by reference), but your `copy_if` won't work to copy to a `std::string` vector, obviously.

Comment: Why the downvote? Its a entirely reasonable question (+1 to compensate)

Comment: @zneak Thanks, I got it! But, I don't think the `copy_if` function is what I actually need since.. I just want to copy the filename (stored as `sa` if the values in `w.Signal().begin() && w.Signal().end()` are above a certain threshold.. But, atm it seems that I'm retruning the double instead I should be returning the string

Comment: No, it's not what you're looking for. `copy_if` takes each element of a range and passes it to the predicate function (your lambda). If your lambda returns true, the single element is copied and the function continues on to the next one.

Comment: Stylistic question... why are you passing the Signal as a const-ref to unique_ptr?  Your code doesn't do anything with the unique_ptr'ishness of the variable, so why not take a const ref to Signal (if an object is always required), or a pointer to const Signal (if it is possible to not pass a Signal).  With these, your function can work on Signals regardless of how their lifetime is being managed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be getting different levels of abstraction confused here. If you're going to work with file names, then you basically want something on this order:

```
std::vector<std::string> input_files;
std::vector<std::string> files_that_contain_sound;

bool file_contains_sound(std::string const &filename) { 
     Wav waveFile = Wav("Samples/" + filename);

     return binned_energy_greater(waveFile, threshold);
}

std::copy_if(input_files.begin(), input_files.end(),
             std::back_inserter(files_that_contain_sound),
             file_contains_sound);
```

For the moment I've put the `file_contains_sound` in a separate function simply to make its type clear -- since you're dealing with file names, it must take a file name as a string, and return a bool indicating whether that file name is one of the group you want in your result set.

In reality, you almost never really want to implement that as an actual function though--you usually want it to be an object of some class that overloads `operator()` (and a lambda is an easy way to generate a class like that). The type involved must remain the same though: it still needs to take a file name (string) as a parameter, and return a bool to indicate whether that file name is one you want in your result set. Everything dealing with what's inside the file will happen inside of that function (or something it calls).